# Create unique integer from an alpha-numeric string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am seeding a database in Rails. The seed data contain ID's, and I need to set those ID's as my primary keys. The primary keys in the seeded data are alpha-numeric. Rails needs its primary keys to be integers. I am thinking there has to be some way to convert an alpha-numeric string to a unique integer. It can't be random. Something equivalent to the decoder ring in your cracker jacks.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to keep the primary keys used in the seeded data? Can you let the database generate the ids for you automatically when you import the data? Or do you have other tables that reference these as-is? If you need custom keys, you could check out something like http://codeherb.com/RailsCustomPk/.

Comment: I would just use the ring and out-source the translation. Why do you think you *need* to use the IDs as PKs? You can create an index on the GUIDs and search just as fast, or just don't seed with weird IDs.

Comment: There are foreign key relationships among the data, so the primary and foreign keys are critical.

Comment: You can create associations using a variety of mechanisms, not just PKs. But that doesn't answer the questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not need to distinguish upper and lower cases, then for example,

```
"fkfj23".to_i(36) # => 941309499
```

Comment: Damn! That was to easy sawa.

Comment: Is there a simple case sensitive version as well?

Comment: Note also that this will [stop at a "extraneous" characters](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i), leading to `'a'.to_i` and `'a-'.to_i` both yielding 10.

Comment: @AlexanderPresber The OP clearly stated that the original string is alpha-numeric.

Comment: @sawa true. But I'd still like to know how to produce a unique integer from an *arbitrary* string?